# Call delegate method on item select

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, uitabbarcontroller

I have 3 viewcontroller in tabbar. I am loading tabbar from appdelegate. Now I want to make an event when user change viewcontroller from tabbar. For that I have wrote delegate method didselectitem in appdelegate and set delegate in my viewcontroller. But delegate method is not called.

In my viewcontroller I am writing this:

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item{
    NSLog(@"tabbar is %@",tabBar.selectedItem);

}
```

in viewdidload:

```
MyAppDelegate.tabBar.delegate=self;
```

Comment: Do you mean tab bar controller delegate? `-tabBarController:didSelectViewController:`?

Comment: Show the code for where you set the delegate.

Comment: Hey put your code, so we can able to know what is wrong in your code.

Comment: maybe you have forgot to set the UITabar delegate to self in appDelegate

Comment: @suhit **Not** the tab bar! The tab bar **view controller**'s delegate.

Comment: @LeoNatan but the didSelect item is the delegate method of UITabBarDelegate protocol. so if it is not set the call will not go the method.

Comment: @suhit The view controller has a delegate method of its own: `-tabBarController:didSelectViewController:`. This is the correct method to listen to.

Comment: @LeoNatan you are correct but vivek has implemented the didSelectItem which is UITabBarDelegate method. The solution should be to implement the tabBarController:didSelectViewController: method.

Comment: @suhit : ok and how to get which viewcontroller is selected

Comment: @vivek as suggested by Leo Nathan, implement the UITabBarControllerDelegate and use the tabBarController:didSelectViewController: to know which viewController got selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to set the delegate of the `UITabBarController` and not the tab bar itself. Also, make sure to implement the correct delegate method: `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:`

More information in the [UITabBarControllerDelegate documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITabBarControllerDelegate).